# Не удаётся установить Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Выполняю всё по инструкции: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x. Вначале в консоли OpenServer ввожу

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Затем после введения команды

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myApp
```

в консоли выходит следующий текст:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v7.0.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v7.0.0): Loading from cache
Created project in laravel-blog
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

и консоль зависает (ни ошибок, ни предупреждений).

В папке myApp появляются новые папки и файлы, но отсутствует папка vendor, то есть проект явно работать не будет без библиотек. В частности команда `php artisan` даёт ошибку, связанную с отсутствием библиотек компонентов.

Как мне устранить эту неполадку и правильно установить Laravel?

Comment: ждать дольше. Установка может занять несколько минут

Comment: @ArchDemon уже прошло больше часа

Comment: Попробуйте в той же папке запустить "composer install -vvv", появится лог Композера по инсталяции зависимостей. Будет более понятно на каком этапе что случается.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, выполнил. Зависание происходит на строке: Reading w:\modules\php\PHP_7.3-x64\..\..\..\userdata\composer\cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache

Comment: Попробуйте composer diagnose. Вообще-то, сейчас, имея хоть что-то на руках, вы вполне можете продолжить поиск в Интернете для решения проблемы. Видимо у вас что-то со связью с packagist.org по HTTPS.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в интернете предлагают самые разные варианты: перезагрузить компьютер, выполнить ```composer clear-cache```, отключить xdebug - ничего не помогает

Answer (score 0):

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
php ./composer.phar update -vv
```